# Insert one column after selecting multiple

Tags: mysql, sql, join, insert, distinct

Here's what my table looks like(MYSQL)

```
Data_Table
org_id | site_id | site | mailing_list | email_address | report_date
1        1         abc.com, list_1,  one@abc.com,   2013-12-13
1        1         abc.com, list_1,  two@abc.com,   2013-12-13
1        1         abc.com, list_1,  three@abc.com, 2013-12-13
1        1         abc.com, list_2,  one@abc.com,   2013-12-13
1        2         cba.com, list_A,  four@abc.com,  2013-12-13
1        2         cba.com, list_A,  one@abc.om,    2013-12-13
2        1         bla.com, listbla, one@abc.com,   2013-12-13
```

So, I'm trying to count(email_address)'s and insert it into the Report_Table.

```
Report_Table(End Product/GOAL)
org_id | site_id | site | count_mailing_lists | aggregate_email_count | unique_email_count
1,       1,        abc.com,      2,                       4,                   3
1,       2,        cba.com,      1,                       2,                   2
```

Let me tell you about the data before I say how I've attempted to solve the problem. So Organizations(org_id) can have any number of sites, these sites can have any number of mailing lists. The mailing lists have email addresses. Multiple mysql queries must be made- so after finding the count(email_address) I have to join it or otherwise add it to the report table.

For finding aggregate_email_count, - it needs to "double-count" the email addresses. So in the Data_Table above, there needs to be an aggregate_email_count on the pairs: Org1/Site1, Org1/Site2, Org2/Site1. The tricky part is one@abc.com --it exists on both mailing lists on Org1, and on the mailing list of Org2.

I figured out the select statement for unique_email_count but do not know how to insert it into a table that is already populated. These counts are part 2 of 3 of a report, so a table that maps all sites to their mailing lists already exists. Here's what that looks like currently.

```
Report_Table
org_id | site_id | site | count_mailing_lists | aggregate_email_count | unique_email_count
1,       1,        abc.com,      NULL,                       NULL,                   NULL
1,       2,        cba.com,      NULL,                       NULL,                   NULL
```

Here's my attempt at finding unique_email_count:

```
SELECT count(distinct b.site_id, b.email) FROM censored.Data_Table b;
```

This returns two columns (site_id&email) and I need to insert email count into Report_Table matching site_id's to site_ids. They both have site_id so I imagine this is straight forward.

Finding aggregate(this doesn't work):

```
INSERT INTO censor.Report_Table (Aggregate_Email_Count)
SELECT b.site_id, b.MAILING_LIST_ID, count(b.email)
FROM censor.Data_Table b
RIGHT JOIN censor.Report_Table a AS b
GROUP BY b.MAILING_LIST_ID;
```

And my third query for count_mailing_lists

```
INSERT INTO censor.Report_Table (Mailing_List_Count)
SELECT count(distinct b.MAILING_LIST_ID, b.site_ID)
FROM censor.Data_Table b;
```

When this is complete the report will show the Unique emails for each org, and the number of emails including ones that exist on multiple mailing lists. This way we can tell our customers "hey, you have one million unique contacts, 8 mailing lists, and 8 million aggregate contacts. Stop bogging down our servers"

Help me by telling me how to join them but for every instance(in the Report_Table) of site_id insert the count(unique), and **for every instance of Org_ID insert count(aggregate).**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
SELECT  
  org_id, site_id, site, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT mailing_list) AS count_mailing_lists,
  COUNT(email_address) AS aggregate_email_count,
  COUNT(DISTINCT email_address) AS unique_email_count
FROM Data_Table
GROUP BY org_id, site_id WITH ROLLUP
```

[On SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f83f5/11/0)

Repopulate your `Report_Data` every time with result of the above query.

The `WITH ROLLUP` option gives you convenient sub-totals as required.

Comment: that SQLFiddle is cool! the Org_ID & mailing_list are primary keys- so with this dummy data it should be 

'Org-1 Site-1 ML-1 Aggregate-4 Unique-3'
'Org-1 Site-1 ML-1 Aggregate-4 Unique-3'

'Org-1 Site-1 ML-2 Aggregate-4 Unique-1'

'Org-2 Site-1 ML-1 Aggregate-1 Unique-1'

so aggregate is paired to org and unique is paired to ML

Comment: Ah, yes. Found the error in it. Corrected and SQLFiddle link updated.

BUT! You can't have 'Org-1 Site-1 ML-1 ...' since the data states that org=1 & site=1 has list_1 AND list_2 so this it's 'Org-1 Site-1 ML-2 ...'

Comment: I don't trust the SQLFiddle because it says cba.com has 3 mailing lists

Comment: That's the rollup row for the whole `org_id = 1` (`site_id = NULL`) which HAS 3 mailing lists :) The `site` column here doesn't have sense so it's just first value that the db engine come across, all other columns apply to whole `org_id = 1`

Comment: the result set on the sqlfiddle has some null values for site_id and/or org_id, and I don't understand how those came into existence. You're right org 1 has 3 mailing lists

Comment: If you delete the `WITH ROLLUP` option from the end of the query and re-run it you will get rid of the null values

Comment: Deleted with rollup and changed 'COUNT(email_address) AS aggregate_email_count' to 'COUNT(distinct email,site_id,mailing_list) AS aggregate_email_count' -- and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
INSERT INTO censor.Report_Table (org_id, site_id, site, count_mailing_lists, 
                                 aggregate_email_count, unique_email_count
                                )
    SELECT dt.org_id, dt.site_id, dt.site,
           count(distinct mailing_list),
           count(email),
           count(distinct email)
    FROM censor.Data_Table dt
    GROUP BY dt.org_id, dt.site_id, dt.site;
```

You can populate the `Report_Table` with a single query -- which suggests that you can also use a view instead of materializing the table.

EDIT:

The above creates all the columns for the reporting table at once.  If you want to just update the value, then you can use an `update` with `join`:

```
update censor.Report_Table rt join
       (SELECT dt.org_id, dt.site_id, dt.site,
               count(distinct mailing_list) as numml,
               count(email) as nume,
               count(distinct email) as numde
        FROM censor.Data_Table dt
        GROUP BY dt.org_id, dt.site_id, dt.site
       ) toupdate
       on rt.org_id = toupdate.org_id and
          rt.site_id = toupdate.site_id
    set unique_email_count = topudate.numde;
```

Comment: I think you have a typo, you put "dt.site_id, dt.site_id" --did you mean org_id? This looks promising

Comment: and selecting dt.site_id and dt.site refers to essentially the same object

Comment: @J-Dizzle . . . Yes, that was a typo.

Comment: This created a new row instead of pairing it to existing data

Comment: I know that I have 20 unique emails and 45 aggregate, but count(email) is returning 720. Thanks for the update(pun intended). 
What keeps count(email) from counting things it shouldnt? even with count(dt.email) it returns 720